# Finding PV of a monthly increasing annuity given annual effective interest rate

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Objective: To find present value of a 10 year annuity immediate with level payments of 2 for the first year, 4 for the second year and 6 for the third year. Given annual effective interest rate of 5%.

My idea is to first consider the increasing amount as 24 dollars each year and compute the monthly interest rate as 0.05/12 = 0.00416667. Plugging all this information into an increasing annuity formula is getting me a final answer of 959.79 which is wrong as the expected answer should be $966.44.

equation i am using is : 24*[(((1.0511618979^-10)-1)/0.04867176)-10(1.0511618979)^-10]/0.05

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addendum added to further refine the formula for the present value of a rising annuity.

---

I was able to reverse-engineer a computation of
$966.4356075$ as follows:

Assume that the interest rate is $i$, where $(1 + i)^{12} = 1.05.$  Note that this formula implies that $i \approx 0.004074124$.

Let $\displaystyle v = \frac{1}{1+i}.$

Then, the present value of a payment of $(1)$, made $k$ months in the future is $v^k$.

Assume that the payments are $2$ for each month for the first $12$ months, then $4$ for each month for the next $12$ months, and so on.  This implies that the last $12$ payments will be $20$ each.

The problem permits some shortcuts.

For $r,s \in \Bbb{Z^+} ~: r < s$, you have that 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=r}^s v^k = v^r\left(1 + v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{s-r}\right) = v^r \times \frac{1 - v^{(s+1-r)}}{1-v}.$

---

The present value of the payments equals

$\displaystyle \left(2 \times \sum_{k=1}^{12} v^k\right)
+ \left(4 \times \sum_{k=13}^{24} v^k\right)
+ \left(6 \times \sum_{k=25}^{36} v^k\right)$

$\displaystyle + \left(8 \times \sum_{k=37}^{48} v^k\right)
+ \left(10 \times \sum_{k=49}^{60} v^k\right)
+ \left(12 \times \sum_{k=61}^{72} v^k\right)$

$\displaystyle + \left(14 \times \sum_{k=73}^{84} v^k\right)
+ \left(16 \times \sum_{k=85}^{96} v^k\right)
+ \left(18 \times \sum_{k=97}^{108} v^k\right)$

$\displaystyle + \left(20 \times \sum_{k=109}^{120} v^k\right).$

Let $u = v^{12}$.

Then, the present value can be more easily expressed as

$$2 \times \frac{1-u}{1-v} \times [v] \times (1 + 2u + 3u^2 + 4u^3 + \cdots + 10u^9).\tag1$$

This formula led to the computation shown in the first line of my answer.

---

**Addendum** 
The formula in (1) above includes the factor of 
$(1 + 2u + 3u^2 + \cdots + 9u^8 + 10u^9).$
An expression of this form is often encountered  when computing the present value of a *rising annuity*.  It therefore seems reasonable to further refine the formula in (1) above by deriving a shortcut for the above factor.

For $u \in \Bbb{R}, ~u \neq 1, ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}:$

let $S(n,u)$ denote $\displaystyle \left[1 + u + u^2 + \cdots + u^n\right] = \frac{1-u^{n+1}}{1 - u}~~~~$ and

let $R(n,u)$ denote $\displaystyle 
\left[1 + 2u + 3u^2 + \cdots + nu^{n-1} + (n+1)u^n\right].$

The goal in this Addendum will be to derive a closed form expression for $R(n,u)$ and then apply it to the formula in (1) above.

$R(n,u)$ may be re-expressed as:

$\left(1 + u + u^2 + \cdots + u^n\right)$ 
$+~ u\left(1 + u + u^2 + \cdots + u^{n-1}\right)$ 
$+~ u^2\left(1 + u + u^2 + \cdots + u^{n-2}\right)$ 
$+~ \cdots $ 
$+~ u^{n-1}\left(1 + u\right)$ 
$+~ u^n\left(1\right).$

Using the formula for $S(n,u)$ above, $R(n,u)$ equals:

$\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[\left(1 - u^{n+1}\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle +~ \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[u\left(1 - u^{n}\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle +~ \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[u^2\left(1 - u^{n-1}\right)\right]$

$+~ \cdots$

$\displaystyle +~ \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[u^{n-1}\left(1 - u^{2}\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle +~ \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[u^{n}\left(1 - u\right)\right].$

This equals:

$\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[\left(1 + u + u^2 + \cdots + u^{n-1} + u^n\right) - (n+1)u^{n+1}\right]$

$\displaystyle =~ \left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right) \times 
\left[\left(\frac{1 - u^{n+1}}{1-u}\right) - (n+1)u^{n+1}\right].$

Therefore,

$$R(n,u) ~=~ \frac{1 - u^{n+1}}{(1-u)^2}  ~-~ 
\frac{(n+1)u^{n+1}}{1-u}.\tag2 $$

In (1) above, the factor of $R(n,u)$ appears with $n = 9$.  Therefore, the formula in (1) above may be re-expressed as:

$\displaystyle (1 + i) = (1.05)^{(1/12)}.$

$\displaystyle v = \frac{1}{1 + i}$.

$\displaystyle u = v^{12}.$

The present value of the rising annuity equals:

$$2 \times \frac{1-u}{1-v} \times [v] \times 
\left[\frac{1 - u^{10}}{(1-u)^2}  ~-~ 
\frac{(10)u^{10}}{1-u}\right].\tag3$$